# why are my calculations messed up in my program?

Tags: c++

Im not quite sure where in my code is causing the problem that causes wrong calculations. When I run the program there is a warning of :

> C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'.

There seems to be something wrong with Tax amount(ta) and Total cost(tc),

```
Current Output:
Cost before Tax: $30.20
Tax Amount: $30.20     
Total Cost: $-107374144.00
ground beef is ex-sponged
Press any key to continue . .


What it **should** be:
Your item name:ground beef
Cost before Tax: $30.20
Tax Amount: $2.64
Total Cost: $32.84
ground beef is ex-sponged
```

---

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class item
{
public:
    item(char* = " " ,float=0.0,int=0,float=0.0);
    ~item();
    void print();
    void calc(int);
private:
    char name[20];
    int quan;
    float cost, tp, cbt, tax, tc;
};
item::~item()
{
    cout << name << " is ex-sponged"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    }
item::item(char *w,float x, int y, float z)
{
    strcpy(name, w);
    cost = x;
    quan=y;
    tp = z;
    tax=cost*quan;
    tc=cbt+tax;
    cbt = cost*quan;
}
void item::print()
{
    cout << "Your item name:" << name << endl;
    cout << "Cost before Tax: $" << cbt << endl;
    cout << "Tax Amount: $" << tax << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost: $" << tc << endl;
}

void item::calc(int n)
{
    quan += n;
    cbt = cost*quan;
     tax = cbt*tp/100;
     tc = cbt + tax;
}

int main()
{
    item i("ground beef", 7.55, 4, 8.75);
    cout << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed;
    i.print();
}
```

Comment: The biggest bug is that you're using floating point numbers to represent money.

Comment: ex-sponged is spelled expunged, although I like your version better.

Comment: Also, there is no good reason to be using C-strings here (you're using `cout`, after all). Use C++ `std::string`.

Comment: don't forget to say explicitly what exactly is wrong, even though it's possible to guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov They do; there's a "what it should be" by the example output.

Answer (score 7):

In the constructor, you're using `cbt` before you initialise it:

```
tc=cbt+tax;
cbt = cost*quan;
```

An uninitialised variable's value is essentially random.

---

Unrelated suggestions:

- Use `std::string` instead of C-style strings (`char` arrays).
- Use `f` suffix on floating literals to give them type `float` instead of `double` (and thus remove the warning): `7.55f` instead of `7.55`, `0.0f` (or `0.f`) instead of `0.0` and so on.
- Don't use a floating point format for money, used a fixed-precision format instead. Rounding errors and inaccuracies in monetary appliations are *bad.*
- Name your parameters in declarations, it serves as self-documentating code.
- In general, it is preferable to use mem-initialiser-lists in constructors instead of assigning to members in the constructor body. This is particularly relevant for members of class type with a nontrivial default constructor (and outright necessary for members which cannot be default-initialised). Since data members are always initialised in order of declaration within class, you'd have to reorder them.

I don't know a fixed-point format offhand, but with the other suggestions, your code would look like this:

```
class item
{
public:
    item(std::string name = " " , float cost = 0.0, int quant = 0, float tp = 0.0);
    ~item();
    void print();
    void calc(int);
private:
    std::string name;
    float cost;
    int quan;
    float tp, tax, cbt, tc;
};

item::~item()
{
    cout << name << " is ex-sponged" << endl;
    system("pause");
}

item::item(std::string name, float cost, int quant, float tp)
  : name(name),
    cost(cost),
    quan(quant),
    tp(tp),
    tax(cost * quant),
    cbt(cost * quant),
    tc(cbt + tax)
{
}

void item::print()
{
    cout << "Your item name:" << name << endl;
    cout << "Cost before Tax: $" << cbt << endl;
    cout << "Tax Amount: $" << tax << endl;
    cout << "Total Cost: $" << tc << endl;
}

void item::calc(int n)
{
    quan += n;
    cbt = cost*quan;
    tax = cbt*tp/100;
    tc = cbt + tax;
}
```

Comment: But you addressed all the warning bells ringing in my head, have a +1 straight back at you ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're using `cbt` before it's initialized:

```
tc=cbt+tax;
cbt = cost*quan;
```

swap these two lines and it should at least work.

Comment: You were faster by a few seconds, have a +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you calculate `tax`:

```
tax=cost*quan;
```

where cost == x == 7.55 and quan == y == 4. So 7.55 * 4 is 30.2. Which is what you get as output. If you expect something else there fix your calculation.

Second:

```
tc=cbt+tax;
cbt = cost*quan;
```

you calculate `tc` using uninitialized `cbt` and then you assign value to `cbt`. So you get garbage in `tc`

Answer (score 0):

*Reason for the warning:*

By default `7.55, 4, 8.75` are doubles. You should specify them as floats: `7.55f, 4.0f, 8.75f`

*Reason for wrong calculations:*

see answer by @Angew and @PaulEvans

Comment: This is true, but not the cause of the bogus total cost value.

Comment: Correct, added disclaimer. I only answered on the warning.